# Strings, ints, and operators in Python

Tags: python, string, operators, int

How can I use an arithmetic operator (input by the user as a string) in an operation? I can print the operation itself, but I want to print the solution!

Here's my clumsy attempt:

```
# Initialise variables

x = 2
y = 3

# Prompt the user for an arithmetic operator

operator = input("Please enter  *,  /,  +,  or  - : ")

# Calculate the operation

result = (str(x) + operator + str(y))

# Display the result

print(result)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`operator` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html), which has functions that perform the same operations as your arithmetic operations.

```
import operator
ops = {'*': operator.mul, '/': operator.div, '+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub}

op = input("Please enter  *,  /,  +,  or  - : ")
result = ops[op](x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn! I had to change 'operator.div' to 'operator.truediv', and then it worked perfectly. I'd upvote your answer, but I don't have enough 'reputation'!

Comment: @felixinutero: your acceptance of my answer is reward enough. :-) Glad to have been of help!